# Using PHP regex to parse XML

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, pcre

How can I use a regular expression to parse XML?

Let's suppose we have the following:

```
$string = '<z>1a<z>2b</z>3c<z>4d</z>5e</z>';
preg_match_all('/<z>(.+)<\/z>/', $string, $result_a);
preg_match_all('/<z>(.+)<\/z>/U', $string, $result_b);
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $result_x);
```

If I run that, then $result_a will have the string (among the items of the array):

```
'1a<z>2b</z>3c<z>4d</z>5e'
```

In addition, variable $result_b will have the strings (among the items of the array):

```
'1a<z>2b'
'4d'
```

Now, I want `$result_x` to have '2b' and '4d' separately, among the items of the array.

What should `$regex` look like?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use non-greedy quantifier:

```
'/<z>(.+?)<\/z>/'
     ___^
```

or change the dot by a negative character class:

```
'/<z>([^z]+)<\/z>/'
```

or

```
'/<z>([^<>]+?)<\/z>/'
```

or, much more convenient, use a [xml parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

Comment: Using that regex builds the same result as the second one I described in the example.

Comment: That's valid, but I would need z to be any kind of XHTML tag. I posted the example using z tag for abstraction purposes, but with z I mean any tag. Using a tag whose name is based on two characters or more with your regex would match in a negative manner the characters that form the name tag, and not the name tag.

Comment: @busce11: So, you have to use a xml parser.

Comment: I can't use an XML parser. Isn't it possible to modify the second expression you proposed, but instead of saying "one or more characters except for a z" declaring "one or more characters that doesn't include the tag name"?

Comment: I tried this: `'/<z>(?!.*<z>.*)(.+)<\/z>/U'` however, it just matched '4d'.

Comment: @busce11: see the third version of regex

Comment: But that's not valid, because the `<z>` tags can contain tags.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can either use a **non-greedy quantifier** or you can use this alternative regex:

```
'/<z>([^<]+)<\/z>/'
```

`[^<]` captures all characters *except* `<`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say it: contents of tags can include < and > characters.